# Cannot create SendGrid account in Azure portal

Tags: azure, sendgrid

I tried to create a Sendgrid account in the Azure portal but after waiting for a long time (couple of minutes?) it says "something went wrong", i.e. I search for Sendgrid in the marketplace, selected the service and pressed the blue Create button. For other services this brings out the settings to use when creating a service.

I've tried this several times and also a colleague tried it with a separate Azure subscription.

Is Sendgrid still supported?

Comment: Are there any logs available in one of the logging systems within Azure, like the Operation Log? We are still using SendGrid, so I guess it's still supported.

Comment: I test in my subscription, it is supported.  Do you select `SendGrid Email Delivery`? If it still does not work, maybe you could change a browser and try again.

Comment: Now it's working. Portal was timing out all day yesterday.

Comment: This seems to happen intermittently ...